# How do I solo a Stalker?

Tags: warframe

I mainly play Nekros, and I don’t have any other frames.

I use ether Reaper, Boltor and Lato. My abilities are useless, because

1. Terrify doesn't work on a stalker,
2. Stalkers are too quick for Soul Punch, (I don’t have enough time to aim)
3. Desecrate could give stalkers a window to dominate in 5 seconds, and
4. While Shadows of the Dead works, I'm dead by the time the animation finishes.

Are there any strategies or mods for soloing a stalker? To take one down, I currently need a full advanced squad with one-shot-kill weapons. I specialise in melee, and I’ve only beat him once by mere luck, but he still escaped. What do I do? I’m mastery 4 rank and I am seeking the hate and despair blueprints. I also don't know how to actually find a stalker; I’ve received 5 death messages, but they have only shown up 3 times since then.

How do I solo a Stalker? If you have any advice regarding this, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: There's an augment for Nekros that lets you offload the damage you take onto your shadows. Get it, use it, always have your shadows up.

Answer (score 2):

Besides gaining and upgrading mods (most notably Serration or its equivalent for your primary) and crafting better weapons (though Boltor isn't that bad) to increase damage output until the encounter becomes trivial and raising your own survivability...

You might want to summon the shadows before he spawns,  (though I recall he could dispel abilities, haven't fought him for a long time), since he sends three messages before appearing.

Once he does spawn, jump around like a monkey and spray him with bullets, with some luck you'll wear him down before he one-shots you.

Another tactic would be to have ridiculously high combo counter and hitting him with a charged melee strike...
Which might require enough progress that the encounter itself would be trivial by that time.

Specters are another venue of gaining meat-shields and possible additional damage. You can get them from Rescue missions (copies of your loadout), Syndicate hit-squads (copies of the hit-squad mobs), or from Clem mission (Clem).

As a side note: at very early stages running in panic and hoping that the teammates you happen to be with will kill him before he downs you is the preferred method, but since you mentioned solo strategy explicitly, I'll leave it as a side note.

Comment: "hoping that the teammates you happen to be with will kill him before he downs you" -- I'm mastery 31 and still like this "tactic": I switch to operator, go into void mode, and stay there until Stalker was killed. Just hold Ctrl and watch the action :)